# How to diagnose USB "stability" issues?

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, mouse, webcam

I need some guidance / pointers on how to diagnose a very odd, intermittent issue I'm experiencing with my system. This is a long one, so let's get stuck in.

### Context

I'm using a Windows 10 PC, on version 2004, build 19041.804. It's a small-form-factor PC I built myself 4/5 years ago. I don't currently have access to extra hardware I could use to isolate and test individual pieces of my system.

I haven't changed *anything* about my setup recently; same devices plugged into the same ports, I have Windows updates blocked using WUB. It's possible Logitech has updated mouse/headset/webcam drivers on me.

### Symptoms

What I'm noticing recently is that intermittently, my Logitech mouse will stop moving on-screen for ~500ms. It recovers just fine without any USB disconnect/error/connection events, **however**, after this symptom, this happens:

- My Rode USB microphone's levels are "reset". The Windows Sound dialog shows the level I set, but until I change it, the *actual* level in recording is as if it were minimum.
- The mouse's "assigned profile" is forgotten by the Logitech software. Power-cycling the mouse fixes this.
- My Logitech webcam will frequently produce "incomplete" or "glitched" frames.
- Sometimes, my Logitech headset will "reboot" - which usually happens when the connection drops.

#### Frequency

Sometimes I can go hours without experiencing this. Sometimes it happens several times in a row, in the space of a few minutes. It doesn't seem to be related to system load nor specific pieces of software.

#### More details

**An important detail** - I have my mouse, microphone & webcam all plugged into a  rando-brand 4-port USB 3.1 Hub at the end of a flat, 2.5m USB 3 extension cable.

Over the last few months I've certainly stressed this hub; I also have a keyboard plugged into it that sometimes has lots of RGB backlighting changing intensity rapidly. It's a very spiky power draw, I could understand this putting a lot of stress on my system. (For instance, I am able to "hear" the power draw through my USB mic recordings)

I initially thought it was limited to just Logitech, but the Rode mic is also affected.

I've used USBLogView to see if it's possible that something is going horribly wrong there, but nothing shows up when the symptom occurs.

I *believe*, because of the mic level resets, that there should be a log somewhere of these events, which would be invaluable in figuring out the cause of the problem.

This... is slowly driving me insane and I'd love to dig in deeper, but I'm at a loss on where next to search.

Comment: Wonder if this is all a physical connection issue? But it also might be a power issue. Not everyone has one of these, but on eBay and Amazon one can buy these small USB voltmeters that basically allows you to connect a live USB connection to them and you can see the exact wattage, amperage and voltage is being consumed. I would recommend connecting that to the hub and see how it all fluctuates… Or perhaps it just drops off completely?

Comment: Great point @Giacomo1968 - I don't think it's physical connection, but I _do_ have a USB volt/ammeter that I can check this out with.

Comment: Tell me about that 2.5m USB 3.x cable. I'm pretty sure most passive cables can't meet the USB 3.x signal integrity spec at much more than 1m, with perhaps very carefully designed and tested high-quality cables reaching 2m. So the fact that you're just casually mentioning a 2.5m USB 3.x cable makes me think you should temporarily replace it with a 1m cable and see if that fixes your problem. It could be causing so much signal problems that eventually your PC's USB host controller chip chokes and resets itself.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, all these USB devices you're talking about are  fully wired devices, right? Like, the Logitech USB mouse has a captive USB cable all the way from the mouse to the PC; you are *NOT* talking about a wireless mouse with a dedicated USB transceiver dongle, right?

Comment: @Spiff I believe you're right on the USB 3 cable. It's only ever supplied ~700ma of current to the hub max. I'll experiment with a shorter cable.

In the hub is a Logitech Unifying transceiver, which is how my mouse is connected. The "power cycle" I do is only on the mouse itself, which made me think that it's not the USB controller resetting, but something more subtle. (Seems likely the driver is resetting, and reconnecting the mouse allows the saved profile to be reapplied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific issue turned out to be a slightly dodgy connection with one of the ports in a USB hub.

As an answer - reseat all USB connections, even if you haven't changed anything recently.